# spring transaction mgmt. and proxy-target-class

Tags: java, spring

Following is my AOP xml declaration.

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" order="100" />
```

I am not using `@Transactional` annotation at my service layer. Still Transaction is working fine, as I have an interceptor for my service layer.

Don't we need `@Transactional` Annotation in case of `proxy-target-class="true"` ???

**I am using Spring -iBatis**

Comment: How do you know transactions are working fine?  In the absence of a transaction, the persistence provider will generally just run in auto-commit mode, so things still "work."

Comment: I know that they are working fine, as roll-back kicks in after partial insert( i.e. if after one insert stmt the other stmt fails.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Transaction is working fine because Transaction interceptor is built into the Spring AOP proxies, automatically triggering a roll back in case of unchecked Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access the DB without an active transaction .If  you are using Spring's hibernate template ot JDBC template, these template will open the Transactions for you . HibernateTemplate does this through the HibernateTransactionManager.

Read the [HibernateTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/HibernateTransactionManager.html) for more info on this or trace the code. You'll find that a Transaction template kicks in .

You will be using @Transactional to define the transaction boundaries, the transaction propagation modes and isolation levels if any.